# integro- (partial) differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, integral-transforms, integro-differential-equations

I'm dealing with a certain kind of integro-differential equation.
The equation reads as :
\begin{equation}
\frac{du(t,x)}{dt} = \int_{\Omega} u(t,y)K(x,y) dy
\end{equation}

for some nice kernel function $K(x,y)$.

I want to do a kind of decay estimate of $\|u(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$. can anyone help me? Any kind of reference would be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this integral equation of Volterra type? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_integral_equation

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question is detailed enough to have one 'correct' answer.  However, using limited analysis knowledge, here is one approach:

$$\sup_{\Omega}|\partial_t||u||^2| = 2\sup_{\Omega}\left |\int_{\Omega} uu_t K dy\right | = 2\sup_{\Omega}\left|\int_{\Omega} u(t,z) \int_{\Omega} u(t,y)K(z,y) dy dz\right| \leq 2\left(\sup_{\Omega}K\right)\left|\int_{\Omega} u(t,z) dz\right|^2.$$

I'm not sure how satisfactory this is.  Of course, if $u$ and/or $\Omega$ are bounded, you can do more.